# Legality of police bringing firearms into federal post office

Tags: police, us-federal-government, firearms, postal-service

Is it legal for all police officers in the United States to carry firearms into post offices, which fall within the jurisdiction of the federal government, when called by post office employees?

Comment: Police don't need a contract to be able to enforce the law within their jurisdiction. This appears to be a nonsense rant, given that "first amendment auditors" is not a formal or official role, and any business can deny entry for good reason, such as safety and security threats.

Comment: I've edited the question to concentrate on the core issue, while removing irrelevant context. Having been so edited, this is actually an interesting question - it's a good chance to explain the difference between federal proprietary, exclusive, and concurrent jurisdiction in the United States.

Comment: Thanks @L235. I found Proprietary in Black's Law Dictionary ( https://thelawdictionary.org/proprietary/) but I don't know how it applies.

Comment: I would think that "when called by post office employees?" (i.e. when the USPS officials called the cops and invited them onto the premises) would be quite distinct from a case where an officer enters a post office uninvited simply to pick up mail or post a letter. It seems like an odd fact pattern, among those that are possible to focus on.

Comment: @ohwilleke, the odd fact pattern was originally discussed in the question but earned downvotes.

Answer (score 10):

[39 CFR § 232.1(l)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/39/232.1) provides that:

> Notwithstanding the provisions of any other law, rule or regulation, no person while on postal property may carry firearms, other dangerous or deadly weapons, or explosives, either openly or concealed, or store the same on postal property, except for official purposes.

Police officers on active duty, enforcing the law at the request of post office employees, appear to be discharging "official purposes".